# How to find Uncatogerized posts and reattach it to default category?

Tags: wordpress

I changed the default category from `uncategorized` to another one, then, I have accidentally deleted `uncategorized` category, which has more than 500 posts attached to it before deletion (check below image)

https://i.postimg.cc/4yGs5vLj/1.jpg

How to find these categories and reattach it to the default category?

P.S.: These posts are not attached to any category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: To do this with code, this query will give you all the Posts without a Category:

```
$postsWithoutCategories = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category__not_in'  => get_terms('category', array(
        'fields'        => 'ids'
    )),
));

$required_category_ID = 123;

if ( $postsWithoutCategories->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $postsWithoutCategories->have_posts() ) {
        $postsWithoutCategories->the_post();
        $post_ID = get_the_ID();
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $required_category_ID );
    }
}
```

In simple terms, the above code is looking for all posts, excluding all that are assigned to any of the categories. Therefore, you will end up with the posts which are not assigned to a category.

You will need to modify the post type and term if you're using a custom post type or custom taxonomy.

Then use [`wp_set_post_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories) to assign them to your required default category.

I have not tested the above code so use with caution.

ORIGINAL ANSWER: Honestly, the fastest way to do this is Bulk Edit:

1. From Screen Options (in the top right), maximize the number of listings displayed on that page.
2. Check each of the uncategorized posts.
3. Select "Edit" from Bulk Actions, then click Apply.
4. Select the Category you want to attach them to, then click Update.

For 500 posts, it shouldn't take you more than a couple of minutes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but i have a huge database and it will be a nightmare to find these 500 posts manually

Comment: * I created a PHP file in the root folder

* add your code in the PHP file as like this <?php Code 

* then call that file in the browser https://example.com/1.php

* but it gave me an error 

This page isn’t working
the site is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: To run WordPress functions, you would need to include('./wp-load.php'); at the start of your PHP file, otherwise all those WordPress functions (WP_Query, have_posts, the_post, get_the_ID, wp_set_post_categories etc) won't work. However, I repeat, use with caution as I haven't checked this, and I'm not familiar with your CPT structure. Backup your database before running any code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. Additional to your answer i add "set_time_limit(0);" to prevent break the loop

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which may be a bit more performant on a database with a lot of categories would be to use the `NOT EXISTS` operator.

To retrieve all posts not assigned to a category.

```php
$posts_without_categories = get_posts([
    'posts_per_page'  => -1, // Return every post available.
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ]
    ],
]);
```

[More information on operators](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)

Once you have the posts, you may do a simple loop to assign them.

```php
// Set this to whatever category you want to assign posts to.
$default_category = 44;

foreach( $posts_without_categories as $post_id ) { 
   wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, [ $default_category ] );
}
```